# Nest Js TypeORM repository.update method not changing multiple fields of an object

Tags: javascript, repository, nestjs, typeorm

Built out an endpoint in my Nest js project that hits this service function when a user submits a form designed to edit an existing organization:

```
async updateOrganization(
    organization: UpdateOrganizationDto,
  ): Promise<Organization> {
    this.organizationRepository.update(organization.organization.id, {
      lastChangedBy: organization.profile.id,
      orgName: organization.organization.orgName,
      orgLead: organization.organization.orgLead,
      orgAsst: organization.organization.orgAsst,
      from: organization.organization.from,
      to: organization.organization.to,
      teamWideReporting: organization.organization.teamWideReporting,
      leadsAddTeamMembers: organization.organization.leadsAddTeamMembers,
      leadsRemoveTeamMembers: organization.organization.leadsRemoveTeamMembers,
    });
    return organization.organization;
```

There are 9 possible fields a user can edit on our UI. Anytime a user hits our update organization (using TypeORM PUT request here), I want the backend to perform a check against all possible fields.

Everything works find when I set up this service function to only change one field, example:

```
async updateOrganization(
    organization: UpdateOrganizationDto,
  ): Promise<Organization> {
    this.organizationRepository.update(organization.organization.id, {
      orgName: organization.organization.orgName
    });
    return organization.organization;
```

However, I'd like a one stop shop to account for all possible updates in a single request to the backend.

I'm hoping this is just a simple typeOrm syntax issue, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to await the promise that is returned from `.update()`:

```
async updateOrganization(
    organization: UpdateOrganizationDto,
  ): Promise<Organization> {
    // let the promise resolve
    await this.organizationRepository.update(organization.organization.id, {
      lastChangedBy: organization.profile.id,
      orgName: organization.organization.orgName,
      orgLead: organization.organization.orgLead,
      orgAsst: organization.organization.orgAsst,
      from: organization.organization.from,
      to: organization.organization.to,
      teamWideReporting: organization.organization.teamWideReporting,
      leadsAddTeamMembers: organization.organization.leadsAddTeamMembers,
      leadsRemoveTeamMembers: organization.organization.leadsRemoveTeamMembers,
    });
    return organization.organization;
```

It could also be an issue with the entity / schema.  You can turn on query and error logging in your typeorm config (where you configure your database connection):
https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/logging

```
{
    host: "localhost",
    ...
    logging: ["query", "error"]
}
```

If you are still facing an issue, please update your post with the organization entity.